# Can't parse JSON object and insert it into database

Tags: json, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem with `JSON` object parsing. The `JSON` represents an order placed by user.

This had worked before, but adding additional Entity/DTO to project caused some problems. To be more specific, JSON looks as below:

```
{
    "orderElements": [
        {
            "product": {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "xxx",
                "description": "yyy",
                "category": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "xxx"
                },
                "price": 11,
                "count": 1
            },
            "quantity": 1
        }
    ],
    "user": {
        "id": 110,
        "lastName": "xxx",
        "firstName": "xxx",
        "addressLine": "xxx",
        "city": "xxx",
        "country": "xxx",
        "zipCode": "123456",
        "phoneNumber": "1234567",
        "password": "xxxx",
        "email": "xxxx",
        "roles": [
            "USER"
        ]
    },
    "orderPlaceTime": null,
    "deliveryAddress": {
        "street": "xxx",
        "city": "xxx",
        "zipCode": "xxx"
    }
}
```

If sent without "*deliveryAddress*" part, `JSON` is being parsed correctly and everything worked just fine. But trying to send JSON with "*deliveryAddress*" and all it's contents results in `NullPointerException`.

Although debugging frontend shows that whole `JSON` is filled correctly - street, city and zipCode fields contain all data that has been put by user (this above is exactly what is send by "POST" - "orderPlaceTime" is filled on backend side by `LocalDateTime.now()` function).

#### ORDER

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "carts")
public class Order extends AbstractEntity {

    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_order")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<OrderElement> orderElements;

    @Column
    private LocalDateTime orderPlaceTime;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_user")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_delivery")
    private DeliveryAddress deliveryAddress;

    public DeliveryAddress getDeliveryAddress() {
        return deliveryAddress;
    }

    public void setDeliveryAddress(DeliveryAddress deliveryAddress) {
        this.deliveryAddress = deliveryAddress;
    }

    public Set<OrderElement> getOrderElements() {
        return orderElements;
    }

    public void setOrderElements(Set<OrderElement> orderElements) {
        this.orderElements = orderElements;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getOrderPlaceTime() {
        return orderPlaceTime;
    }

    public void setOrderPlaceTime(LocalDateTime orderPlaceTime) {
        this.orderPlaceTime = orderPlaceTime;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

}
```

#### DELIVERYADDRESS

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "delivery_address")
public class DeliveryAddress extends AbstractEntity {

    @Column
    private String street;

    @Column
    private String city;

    @Column
    private String zipCode;

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public String getZipCode() {
        return zipCode;
    }

    public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

}
```

#### ORDER CONVERTER

```
@Component
public class OrderConverter implements Converter<Order, OrderDTO> {

    private final OrderElementConverter orderElementConverter;
    private final DeliveryAddressConverter deliveryAddressConverter;
    private final UserConverter userConverter;

    public OrderConverter(OrderElementConverter orderElementConverter, DeliveryAddressConverter deliveryAddressConverter, UserConverter userConverter) {
        this.orderElementConverter = orderElementConverter;
        this.deliveryAddressConverter = deliveryAddressConverter;
        this.userConverter = userConverter;
    }

    @Override
    public Order convertToEntity(OrderDTO dto) {
        Order order = new Order();
        order.setId(dto.getId());
        order.setUser(userConverter.convertToEntity(dto.getUser()));
        order.setOrderPlaceTime(now());
        Set<OrderElement> entitySet = new HashSet<>();
        for (OrderElementDTO o : dto.getOrderElements()) {
            entitySet.add(orderElementConverter.convertToEntity(o));
        }
        order.setOrderElements(entitySet);
    // this below throws NullPointerException --> dto.getDeliveryAddressDTO();
        order.setDeliveryAddress(deliveryAddressConverter.convertToEntity(dto.getDeliveryAddressDTO()));
        return order;
    }
}
```

#### DELIVERY ADRESS CONVERTER

```
@Component
public class DeliveryAddressConverter implements Converter<DeliveryAddress, DeliveryAddressDTO> {

    @Override
    public DeliveryAddress convertToEntity(DeliveryAddressDTO dto) {
        DeliveryAddress deliveryAddress = new DeliveryAddress();
        deliveryAddress.setId(dto.getId());
        deliveryAddress.setCity(dto.getCity());
        deliveryAddress.setZipCode(dto.getZipCode());
        deliveryAddress.setStreet(dto.getStreet());
        return deliveryAddress;
    }
}
```

And I have no idea why `deliveryAddress` is null if it is sent by frontend correctly.

Thank you for all answers and suggestions

#### EDIT

It turned out as pointed by JB Nizet fields in OrderDTO had "deliveryAddressDTO" rather than "deliveryAddress". Cutting "DTO" from names fixed the issue:

```
public class OrderDTO extends AbstractDTO {

    private Set<OrderElementDTO> orderElements;

    private LocalDateTime orderPlaceTime;

    private UserDTO user;

    private DeliveryAddressDTO deliveryAddress;
    // private DeliveryAddressDTO deliveryAddressDTO; <-- wrong name, methods also aligned

    public DeliveryAddressDTO getDeliveryAddress() {
        return deliveryAddress;
    }

    public void setDeliveryAddressDTO(DeliveryAddressDTO deliveryAddress) {
        this.deliveryAddress = deliveryAddress;
    }


    public Set<OrderElementDTO> getOrderElements() {
        return orderElements;
    }

    public void setOrderElements(Set<OrderElementDTO> orderElements) {
        this.orderElements = orderElements;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getOrderPlaceTime() {
        return orderPlaceTime;
    }

    public void setOrderPlaceTime(LocalDateTime orderPlaceTime) {
        this.orderPlaceTime = orderPlaceTime;
    }

    public UserDTO getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(UserDTO user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share class DeliveryAddressConverter. Order cannot be null and so dto. So it seems deliveryAddressConverter could be null.

Comment: it is added now :)

Comment: How do you parse the JSON to make it an OrderDTO? Where is the code of this DTO? Note that the property in the JSON is named `deliveryAddress`, but the field in OrderDTO seems to be named `deliveryAddressDTO`.

Comment: so it turned out that indeed in OrderDTO I had used deliveryAddressDTO as a field name. but now SQL throws: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'id_delivery' cannot be null"

Comment: You haven't saved your DeliveryAddress before setting it into the order, and there is no cascade on the association.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out as pointed by JB Nizet fields in OrderDTO had "deliveryAddressDTO" rather than "deliveryAddress". Cutting "DTO" from names fixed the issue:

```
public class OrderDTO extends AbstractDTO {

    private Set<OrderElementDTO> orderElements;

    private LocalDateTime orderPlaceTime;

    private UserDTO user;

    private DeliveryAddressDTO deliveryAddress;
    // private DeliveryAddressDTO deliveryAddressDTO; <-- wrong name, methods also aligned

    public DeliveryAddressDTO getDeliveryAddress() {
        return deliveryAddress;
    }

    public void setDeliveryAddressDTO(DeliveryAddressDTO deliveryAddress) {
        this.deliveryAddress = deliveryAddress;
    }


    public Set<OrderElementDTO> getOrderElements() {
        return orderElements;
    }

    public void setOrderElements(Set<OrderElementDTO> orderElements) {
        this.orderElements = orderElements;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getOrderPlaceTime() {
        return orderPlaceTime;
    }

    public void setOrderPlaceTime(LocalDateTime orderPlaceTime) {
        this.orderPlaceTime = orderPlaceTime;
    }

    public UserDTO getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(UserDTO user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

Also id_delivery issue has been fixed by JB Nizet, as well - adding cascade.ALL annotation to the ManyToOne solved all problems.

Thank you!